# How to use async to parallelize heavy computation?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, rust-tokio, rust-async-std

I would like to perform the following processing in multi-threads using [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) or [async-std](https://crates.io/crates/async-std). I have read tutorials but I haven't seen any mention of parallelizing a `for` loop. In my program, all threads refer to the same array but will access different locations:

```
let input_array: Array2<f32>;  
let output_array: Array2<f32>;
for i in 0..roop_num {
  let res = do_some_func(&input_array, idx);
  output_array.slice_mut(s![idx, ...]) .assign(&res);
}
```

I would like to change the `for` loop to use parallel processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokio or async-std deal with concurrency, not parallelism. If you need the data parallelism then [rayon](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/concurrency/parallel.html) is a better choice. If you are using an `Iterator`, then [`.chunks()`](http://docs.piston.rs/imageproc/rayon/iter/trait.IndexedParallelIterator.html#method.chunks) method is good. For more imperative approach you can use [`.par_chunks_mut()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230633/how-to-obtain-the-chunk-index-in-rayons-par-chunks-mut).